# instructions for sublime text 2 kindari xdebug plugin

Tags: php, xdebug, sublimetext2

I am trying to install the sublime text 2 plugin  https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug/blob/master/README.md. But am having trouble getting it working:

So far I have a few questions:

where it says:

```
"settings": {
    "xdebug": { "url": "http://your.web.server" }
}
```

my local wamp server is "htp://127-0-0-1" -- is this what it means?

Also after following the Xdebug installation wizard the PHP.ini file looks like this :

```
zend_extension = \xampp-portable\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp-portable\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp-portable\tmp"
```

is this correct?

3) Also to initiate a session do I need to have a XDEBUG_SESSION_START present in the URL.I have installed xdebug helper in chrome, and tried htp://127-0-0-1/test1/index?XDEBUG_SESSION_START in chrome's address bar

Thank you very much in advance. even answering 1 or 2 of the questions would be a big help

regards,

Bill

Hi Bob - Thanks for looking at this. by following your instructions I have a portion of it working. I'll play with it a little more and ask a followup question in the next 24-48 hours - Bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The sublime text xdebug plugin will use this path to enable and disable xdebug session on the server. The url should be the same as the one you are using to connect to the server in your browser. In this case, that would be `"xdebug": { "url": "http://127.0.0.1" }`.

   If you are using the Chrome xdebug helper you can skip configuring that part, but you will need to edit the IDE key in the options for the Chrome extension. Just change the dropdown to `Other` and enter `sublime.xdebug` as the value.
2. There are a few problems with your xdebug settings. First, you must use the full path when specifying the extension. Second, all of your settings are commented out with `;`'s.

   Here's a simplified config to get you started. I guessed what the path was to your xdebug dll, so edit it if it does not reflect where your file is actually located.

   ```
   zend_extension = "C:/xampp-portable/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll"
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
   xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
   xdebug.remote_port = 9000
   ```

   Once you have edited and saved your php.ini file, restart/reload xampp and check phpinfo() to make sure xdebug is active.
3. Item #1 already handled this. If you set the url in your .sublime-project file, it will automatically open your default browser with `http://127.0.0.1/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug`. This is really just a convenience helper to start and stop the debugging session, and can be safely ignored.

   I much prefer using the Chrome xdebug helper instead. Just click the bug in the address bar to enable/disable the debug session.